# Any Java based framework for Automating C++ / Python code?

Tags: java, c++, automation

I am trying to explore (or) find is there any Java based Automation framework available for automating C++ based code (Client Server application).  There are other C++ Automation framework available but, I am really interested to know the involvement of JAVA.  Appreciate any help in finding it out.

Comment: What sort of test scenarios are you trying to automate? The frameworks or libraries used will depend on the application under test. For example, are you trying to achieve GUI automation, test that a web server or API behaves as expected, or something else? TestNG in conjunction with other Java libraries can probably cover a lot of scenarios, depending on what you need to accomplish.